# pyplot.scatter reduce marker size

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is an example of a scatter plot with high 2D point density, just for illustration.

How can I reduce the size of the markers to better distinguish the individual points? The size of the plot should remain as it is.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from matplotlib import cm

np.random.seed(10)

n=3000

x = np.arange(n)
z = np.sin(x/n)
y = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n))

colvals = preprocessing.minmax_scale(z)

plt.scatter(x, y, color=cm.rainbow(colvals), marker='.')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @tdy I am wrong, what I said. That is the solution. Thank you very much. You can write this as an answer and I will mark it as solved. It seems that s has no lower boundary?

Comment: No problem. Any float is valid (even negative values will only give a warning), so the practical lower bound is just whatever is perceptible to the eye for a given figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) has a parameter `s` for controlling the marker size.

- `s` can either be a single float that applies to all points, e.g. all size 5:

  ```
  s = 5
  plt.scatter(x, y, color=cm.viridis(colvals), marker='.', s=s)
  ```

  [image]
- Or `s` can be an array of sizes that maps to every point, e.g. size 5 when `z > 0.5` and size 30 otherwise:

  ```
  s = np.where(z > 0.5, 5, 30)
  plt.scatter(x, y, color=cm.viridis(colvals), marker='.', s=s)
  ```

  [image]

---

Note that to match the size of scatter and plot markers, the plot marker's `markersize` should be the square root of the scatter marker's `s`:

```
s = 900

plt.scatter(-1, 0, s=s, color='tab:orange')
plt.plot(1, 0, 'o', markersize=s ** 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: I swapped out `rainbow` for `viridis` since the [rainbow colormap should be avoided](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4118486?arnumber=4118486) when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the interesting paper, many researchers still use rainbow or monochrome color maps with increasing brightness.